# Как добавить товар в корзину пользователя, зная его USER_ID?

Tags: php, битрикс

Задача состоит в том, чтобы, имея ID конкретного пользователя, получить актуальную корзину и добавить\изменить товары в ней.

1. Получаем ID покупателя

```php
    $saleUser = \CSaleUser::GetList(['USER_ID' => $USER_ID]);
```

2. Достаем корзину для необходимого пользователя

```php
    $basket = \Sale\Basket::loadItemsForFUser($saleUser['ID'], 's1');
```

3. Работаем с экземпляром класса Bitrix\Sale\Basket и редактируем товар

```php
    /** int $productId ID товара */
    /** int $quantity количество */
    if ($item = $basket->getExistsItem('catalog', $productId)) {
        $item->setField('QUANTITY', $item->getQuantity() + $quantity);
    }
    else {
        $item = $basket->createItem('catalog', $productId);
        $item->setFields(array(
            'QUANTITY' => $quantity,
            'CURRENCY' => 'RUB',
            'LID' => 's1',
            'PRODUCT_PROVIDER_CLASS' => 'CCatalogProductProvider',
        ));
    }
    $basket->save();
```

Но при этом товары в корзине не меняются. Данная проверка всегда уходит в false и новый товар тоже не добавляется.

Также пробовал таким образом:

```php
    $basketItems = $basket->getBasketItems();
    foreach ($basketItems as $basketItem) {
        if ($basketItem->getProductId() == $productId) {
             // товар находится, но при использовании $basketItem->setField('QUANTITY', $quantity) ничего не меняется
        }
    }
```

Использовал как и

```php
    $basketItem->save();
```

так и

```php
    $basket->save();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено таким образом

```
    $basketItems = $basket->getBasketItems();
    foreach ($basketItems as $basketItem) {
        if ($basketItem->getProductId() == $productId) {
            $item = $basket->getItemById($basketItem->getId());
            if ($item) {
                $item->setField('QUANTITY', $item->getQuantity() + $quantity);
            }
            $basket->save();
        }
    }`
```